# Non-clustered stateful EJB in WildFly 10

Tags: ejb, cluster-computing, wildfly, stateful

I have an J2EE client-server application, using Wildfly 10. I'm using stateful EJBs so the clients can communicate with the server, use load balancing and failover.

In one production environment we will have dozens of servers on a cluster. So I'm worried about clustering, because I don't want EVERY stateful EJB been replicated over EVERY server in the cluster. I think that overhead will be terrible.

Is there any way to configure my stateful EJBs or WilfFly so muy EJBs won't be replicated but still load balancing over the cluster ?

Comment: EJB 3.2 provides a mechanism to disable replication/passivation via `@Stateful(passivationCapable=false)`.

Comment: I'm confused about passivation an replication. I think passivation is when and stateful EJB is not used for a long time, and replication is replicating the stateful EJB state over the cluster. ¿ I'm right ? So (passivationCapable=false) disables passivation AND replication ?

Comment: Take a look in this Paul Ferraro comment https://developer.jboss.org/message/931539#931539, it has a good explanation about this topic.

Comment: Very clear comment. Because we have dozens of ejbs, we changed Wildfly subsystem "urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:4.0" stateful configuration from: <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="distributable" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/> to <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>. We think this change is equivalent to set @Stateful(passivationCapable=false) to all of our ejbs

Comment: Thanks Federico, I think your first comment is the right answer, feel free to post it as a solution.